Unable to connect to teamcenter with new HTTPS url using manually added wsdls
I am stuck in this problem where I have to connect to Teamcenter (TC14) with HTTPS endpoint URL using WSDLs manually provided as files (because they are not exposed anymore). Trying them in browser will show:-
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /tc/services/Core-2006-03-Session and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>

The code for the login is provided below:-
public class TeamcenterConnectionService
{
    public TeamcenterConnectionService(string sessionURL, string userId, string password)
    {
        this.session = new Core0603SessionClient();
        session.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(sessionURL);
        LoginResponse loginResponse = login(userId, password);
    }

    public LoginResponse login(string userId, string password)
    {
        LoginInput loginInput = new LoginInput();
        loginInput.username = userId;
        loginInput.password = password;
        loginInput.sessionDiscriminator = RandomString(14);

        LoginResponse loginResponse = null;
    
        try
        {
            loginResponse = session.login(loginInput);
            return loginResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}

Here, sessionURL is the HTTPS url (Dummy url that is similar to original:-https://abctc14qwertyu.test.com:6969/tc/services/Core-2006-03-Session) that I am supposed to use for login.
In web.config, I have set the binding as below for now:-
binding name="Core0603SessionSoapBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" >
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
    </security>

I have tried all different security modes and getting different errors:-
For security mode = "None" and "TransportCredentialOnly", I get error:- "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.Parameter name: via"

For security mode = "Transport", I get error:- "An error occurred in the presentation tier. %"

For security mode = "TransportWithMessageCredential", I get error:- "The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials."

Not to be used here but just for reference:-
For security mode = "Message", I get error:- "BasicHttp binding requires that BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType be equivalent to the BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate credential type for secure messages. Select Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential security for UserName credentials."

What should I do to make this work?
NOTE:-

The HTTPS url is being used by another team ensuring that the URL is up and running.

session.ClientCredentials is readonly, so unable to add username or password while using "TransportWithMessageCredential".

This code with security mode = "None" works for HTTP TC11 URL (same WSDL). Is the WSDL not configured to work for HTTPS?


